# Check folder existence Ajax - php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to check existence of a folder called `$subdomaine` in the directory `\cms\sites\` on the keyup.
Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#subdomain').keyup(subdomain_check);
}); 
function subdomain_check(){ 
var subdomain = $('#subdomain').val();
if(subdomain == "" || subdomain.length < 4){
$('#subdomain').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
$('#tick').hide();
}else{
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: 'subdomain='+ subdomain,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
if(response == 1){
$('#subdomain').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');    
$('#tick').hide();
$('#cross').fadeIn();
}else{
$('#subdomain').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
$('#cross').hide();
$('#tick').fadeIn();
     }
 }
 });
 }
 }
</script>
```

ajax.php :

```
<?php 
$dirname = $_SESSION["subdomain"];
$filename = DOCUMENT_ROOT."sites/".$dirname;

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
   echo "The directory $dirname exists.";
    exit;
}
```

How do I check the existence of the folder at the input ?

Thanks

Comment: `is_dir` http://us3.php.net/is_dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to use `is_dir()` function to check given file name is directory.

```
if (is_dir($filename)) {
  echo "The directory $dirname exists.";
  exit;
}
```

For your ajax response,

```
 if (is_dir($filename)) {
   echo 1;      
}else{
   echo 0;
}
```

Comment: You have used `if(response == 1){` in your javascript so you need to change your php ajax response text as given above

Answer (score 1):

better way---

NB: change $_SESSION to $_POST too.

```
<?php 
 $dirname = $_POST["subdomain"];  //look this
 $dir = DOCUMENT_ROOT."sites/".$dirname;

if(file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir)){
   echo "The directory $dirname exists.";
   exit;
} 

?>
```